# Required a interactive widget/element on medium.com

Tags: html, css, iframe, embed, medium-editor

I've been toying with an idea to enhance my articles by incorporating interactive flashcards. These flashcards would provide an engaging way for readers to grasp key concepts. After some research, I've compiled a list of potential solutions, which include `SAAS` sites and educational platforms that offer flashcard features.
The list currently includes:

- Wordwall
- Anki
- Quizlet
- WP Flashcards

I've been experimenting with these platforms, and I've found that Quizlet aligns most closely with what I envision. However, when I embed Quizlet flashcards into my Medium posts, they don't appear as interactive elements. Instead, they show up as simple links, which doesn't provide the intended user experience.

[image]

So, here's where I could use your expertise! Has anyone encountered a similar situation or found a workaround for this? I'm thinking of creating a widget out of the Quizlet embed element and linking it to Medium. If you have any suggestions or ideas on how to make this work seamlessly, I'd greatly appreciate your input.

**Expected Result:**

[image]

I did try to embed the quizlet `iframe` into various sites and turn into a widget. But yet didn't work.

For the information [these are the providers](https://embed.ly/providers) which and when we embed the element turns into interactive one.

**Point to be taken:** I just want to user who is reading my article have a quick drill on the concepts learn in last 15 or 20 mins using flashcards. This is a great way to memorize concepts, definition when there is a lot in plate on top of that everything looks similar.

Few sites which came across:

- https://codebeautify.org/html-iframe-generator
- https://help.boldbi.com/embedding-options/embedding-sdk/embedding-a-widget/
- https://www.torontoteachermom.com/2020/04/how-to-embed-quizlet-flashcards.html
- https://support.learnworlds.com/support/solutions/articles/12000046873-how-to-embed-and-use-quizlet-flashcards#Flashcards
- https://medium.com/@pragprog/creating-a-widget-to-embed-in-other-sites-eeb4517db939

Answer (score 0):

It's fantastic that you're considering incorporating interactive flashcards into your articles to enhance the learning experience for your readers. The challenge you're facing with Quizlet not displaying as interactive elements on Medium can be a common issue due to the platform's restrictions on certain embeds.
But guess what? I cracked it!

Here's the scoop on how to make those elements pop on Medium:

- **GitHub Gist is the Hero:** Turns out, GitHub Gist allows Medium to play nice and lets you embed things smoothly. No more plain links – we're talking the whole interactive shebang!
- **Gist Creation Magic:** First, trot over to [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/) and conjure up a new gist.

**Quick note:** make sure the file name ends in `.md` for a slick preview of your code.

[image]

- **Gist Birth:** Click that `Create Gist` button – don't fret if it's public or private for now. Once it's born, head to the `Share` section.
- It defaults to `embed`, but hold your horses – that doesn't groove with Medium. Click the little arrow next to it and choose `Share: Copy Shareable Link for Gist`.
- **Get That URL:** Now, gaze upon the output box next door; it's flaunting your gist's URL. **Copy that magic link.**

[image]

- **Medium -> Gist:** Return to your Medium article, slap that link in, hit enter, and boom! Give it a couple of seconds, and voilà – your gist appears in all its preview glory instead of a wall of code.

[image]

**Here's a example I tried:** I threw my [Buy Me a Coffee](https://gist.github.com/codeapplied/d9f2bdfef1ab850faa0e6df652e1e03f) widget into a gist, copied the link, and casually dropped it into [my Medium article](https://yaarjoy.medium.com/namaste-im-joypal-81d24fbd066c). It's interactive and looks way snazzier than just linking some text.

[image]

And let's be real, after the struggle, finding this way around is a bit crazy, right? But hey, that's the charm of tech adventures! Happy embedding!